# Go url parameters mapping

Tags: go, routes, url-mapping

Is there a native way for inplace url parameters in native `Go`?

For Example, if I have a URL: `http://localhost:8080/blob/123/test` I want to use this URL as `/blob/{id}/test`.

This is not a question about finding `go` libraries. I am starting with the basic question, does go itself provide a basic facility to do this natively.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no built in simple way to do this, however, it is not hard to do.

This is how I do it, without adding a particular library. It is placed in a function so that you can invoke a simple `getCode()` function within your request handler.

Basically you just split the `r.URL.Path` into parts, and then analyse the parts.

```
// Extract a code from a URL. Return the default code if code
// is missing or code is not a valid number.
func getCode(r *http.Request, defaultCode int) (int, string) {
        p := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")
        if len(p) == 1 {
                return defaultCode, p[0]
        } else if len(p) > 1 {
                code, err := strconv.Atoi(p[0])
                if err == nil {
                        return code, p[1]
                } else {
                        return defaultCode, p[1]
                }
        } else {
                return defaultCode, ""
        }
}
```

Comment: [Vestigo](https://husobee.github.io/golang/urlrouter/vestigo/2015/09/22/vesigo.html) is another good router.

Comment: Starting with Go 1.22 path parameters are supported

Comment: Go 1.22 has added support for path parameters and wildcards.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78045394/1733315

Answer (score 16):

Well, without external libraries you can't, but may I recommend two excellent ones:

1. httprouter - https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter - is extremely fast and very lightweight. It's faster than the standard library's router, and it creates 0 allocations per call, which is great in a GCed language.
2. Gorilla Mux - http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux -
   Very popular, nice interface, nice community.

Example usage of httprouter:

```
func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s!\n", ps.ByName("name"))
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/hello/:name", Hello)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Comment: If you can't without external libraries, how are those libraries implemented?

Comment: @райтфолд they are implemented at the lowest level, bypassing the default http router. I understood OP's question as "is there a way to do this using the default http library". Well - just to implement your own router. And there really isn't a need for that.

Comment: I'd also recommend chi - https://github.com/go-chi/chi

Answer (score 4):

What about trying using regex, and find a named group in your url, like [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4xUqVCTqC5S):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
)

var myExp = regexp.MustCompile(`/blob/(?P<id>\d+)/test`) // use (?P<id>[a-zA-Z]+) if the id is alphapatic

func main() {

    s := "http://localhost:8080/blob/123/test"

    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(u.Path)

    match := myExp.FindStringSubmatch(s) // or match := myExp.FindStringSubmatch(u.Path)
    result := make(map[string]string)
    for i, name := range myExp.SubexpNames() {
        if i != 0 && name != "" {
            result[name] = match[i]
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("id: %s\n", result["id"])

}
```

output

```sh
/blob/123/test
id: 123
```

Below full code to use it with url, that is receiving `http://localhost:8000/hello/John/58` and returning `http://localhost:8000/hello/John/58`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

var helloExp = regexp.MustCompile(`/hello/(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<age>\d+)`)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    match := helloExp.FindStringSubmatch(req.URL.Path)
    if len(match) > 0 {
        result := make(map[string]string)
        for i, name := range helloExp.SubexpNames() {
            if i != 0 && name != "" {
                result[name] = match[i]
            }
        }
        if _, err := strconv.Atoi(result["age"]); err == nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %v year old named %s!", result["age"], result["name"])
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, not accepted age!")
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Wrong url\n")
    }
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/hello/", hello)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

Comment: While `regexp` would work, it is a lot slower than the accepted answer. Also there are enough routers written nowadays that do this and we really do not need to reimplement this again and again.

Answer (score 2):

How about writing your own url generator (extend `net/url` a little bit) as below.

```
// --- This is how does it work like --- //
url, _ := rest.NewURLGen("http", "stack.over.flow", "1234").
    Pattern(foo/:foo_id/bar/:bar_id).
    ParamQuery("foo_id", "abc").
    ParamQuery("bar_id", "xyz").
    ParamQuery("page", "1").
    ParamQuery("offset", "5").
    Do()

log.Printf("url: %s", url) 
// url: http://stack.over.flow:1234/foo/abc/bar/xyz?page=1&offset=5

// --- Your own url generator would be like below --- //
package rest

import (
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "strings"

    "straas.io/base/errors"

    "github.com/jinzhu/copier"
)

// URLGen generates request URL
type URLGen struct {
    url.URL

    pattern    string
    paramPath  map[string]string
    paramQuery map[string]string
}

// NewURLGen new a URLGen
func NewURLGen(scheme, host, port string) *URLGen {
    h := host
    if port != "" {
        h += ":" + port
    }

    ug := URLGen{}
    ug.Scheme = scheme
    ug.Host = h
    ug.paramPath = make(map[string]string)
    ug.paramQuery = make(map[string]string)

    return &ug
}

// Clone return copied self
func (u *URLGen) Clone() *URLGen {
    cloned := &URLGen{}
    cloned.paramPath = make(map[string]string)
    cloned.paramQuery = make(map[string]string)

    err := copier.Copy(cloned, u)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    return cloned
}

// Pattern sets path pattern with placeholder (format `:<holder_name>`)
func (u *URLGen) Pattern(pattern string) *URLGen {
    u.pattern = pattern
    return u
}

// ParamPath builds path part of URL
func (u *URLGen) ParamPath(key, value string) *URLGen {
    u.paramPath[key] = value
    return u
}

// ParamQuery builds query part of URL
func (u *URLGen) ParamQuery(key, value string) *URLGen {
    u.paramQuery[key] = value
    return u
}

// Do returns final URL result.
// The result URL string is possible not escaped correctly.
// This is input for `gorequest`, `gorequest` will handle URL escape.
func (u *URLGen) Do() (string, error) {
    err := u.buildPath()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    u.buildQuery()

    return u.String(), nil
}

func (u *URLGen) buildPath() error {
    r := []string{}
    p := strings.Split(u.pattern, "/")

    for i := range p {
        part := p[i]
        if strings.Contains(part, ":") {
            key := strings.TrimPrefix(p[i], ":")

            if val, ok := u.paramPath[key]; ok {
                r = append(r, val)
            } else {
                if i != len(p)-1 {
                    // if placeholder at the end of pattern, it could be not provided
                    return errors.Errorf("placeholder[%s] not provided", key)
                }
            }
            continue
        }
        r = append(r, part)
    }

    u.Path = strings.Join(r, "/")
    return nil
}

func (u *URLGen) buildQuery() {
    q := u.URL.Query()
    for k, v := range u.paramQuery {
        q.Set(k, v)
    }
    u.RawQuery = q.Encode()
}
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does this do the inverse of what was asked?

Answer (score 2):

With `net/http` the following would trigger when calling `localhost:8080/blob/123/test`

```
http.HandleFunc("/blob/", yourHandlerFunction)
```

Then inside `yourHandlerFunction`, manually parse `r.URL.Path` to find `123`.

Note that if you don't add a trailing `/` it won't work. The following would only trigger when calling `localhost:8080/blob`:

```
http.HandleFunc("/blob", yourHandlerFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 19-Sep-22, with go version 1.19, instance of http.request URL has a method called Query, which will return a map, which is a parsed query string.

```
func helloHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // when request URL is `http://localhost:3000/?first=hello&second=world`
    fmt.Println(req.URL.Query()) // outputs , map[second:[world] first:[hello]] 

    res.Write([]byte("Hello World Web"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, go can do this natively without requiring extra libraries.  In go 1.22 you can do this without needing to parse the path or use hard-coded path indices, as suggested in the accepted answer.  As of go 1.22, go will parse placeholders in a ServeMux matched url.  From the release notes, "The new method Request.PathValue returns path wildcard values from a request and the new method Request.SetPathValue sets path wildcard values on a request."  In addition you can specify the method to handle.  See the Go blog article [routing-enhancements](https://go.dev/blog/routing-enhancements).  For your example,

`http.HandleFunc("GET /blob/{id}/test", handleBlob)`

which will handle a GET or HEAD request to paths like `/blob/1/test` or `/blob/abc/test`. Further, the request handler can retrieve the value in the matched placeholder `{id}` using the handler's Request argument and the PathValue method; `request.PathValue("id")` would yield "1" and "abc" in the examples respectively.

```
func handleBlob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := r.PathValue("id")
    // do stuff with id
}
```

The code is simple and easy to read with no hard-code path indices.

See the go docs for [PathValue](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@master#Request.PathValue) and [ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux).

Url matching is only part of what a router does.  Pluggable middleware is often included in a router package's feature set and this is not address by the PathValue feature.

Answer (score -1):

No way without standard library. Why you don't want to try some library? I think its not so hard to use it, just go get bla bla bla

I use [Beego](http://beego.me/). Its MVC style.

Comment: Before I go searching for a library, I want to know if it can be done in golang. (Also, Stackoverflow bans questions asking about choosing libraries)

Comment: Please provide a sample solution if you are suggesting something. Your answer is not helpful to the readers. Provide a sample to question asked using `Beego`

Answer (score -1):

how about a simple utility function ?

```
func withURLParams(u url.URL, param, val string) url.URL{
    u.Path = strings.ReplaceAll(u.Path, param, val)
    return u
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
u, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8080/blob/:id/test")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
u := withURLParams(u, ":id","123")

// now u.String() is http://localhost:8080/blob/123/test
```

Comment: This is the opposite of the question, the question is if the url is: `http://localhost:8080/blob/123/test` the appis required to read it and tell the `:id = 123`

Answer (score -10):

If you need a framework and you think it will be slow because it's 'bigger' than a router or net/http, then you 're wrong.

[Iris](http://iris-go.com) is the fastest **go web framework** that you will ever find, so far according to all benchmarks.

Install by

```
  go get gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6
```

Django templates goes easy with iris:

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6"
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter"
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/view" // <-----

)

func main() {

    app := iris.New()
    app.Adapt(iris.DevLogger())
    app.Adapt(httprouter.New()) // you can choose gorillamux too
    app.Adapt(view.Django("./templates", ".html")) // <-----

    // RESOURCE: http://127.0.0.1:8080/hi
    // METHOD: "GET"
    app.Get("/hi", hi)

    app.Listen(":8080")
}

func hi(ctx *iris.Context){
   ctx.Render("hi.html", iris.Map{"Name": "iris"})
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about iris before you use it, eg: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/57w79c/why_you_really_should_stop_using_iris/