# Net/http Simple Dynamic Routes

Tags: go

I am looking for a simple way to create dynamic routes with net/http (no routers like mux etc.)
Here is my current code:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        pages := r.URL.Query()["q"]
        if len(pages) == 0 {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "§§§§§§§§§§ You need to specify a page §§§§§§§§§§")
            return
        }

        page := pages[0]

        var a Page
        err := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM pages where page = ?", page).Scan(&a.Page, &a.Date, &a.Url)
        a.Year = time.Now().UTC().Year()
        if err != nil {
            if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "Page %s not found", page)
                return
            } else {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "Some error happened")
                return
            }
        }

        http.Redirect(w, r, a.Url, 301)

    })
```

So now the URL sample.com/?q= works dynamically.
My objective is to work without having to use r.URL.Query()["q"] so directly /pagename

This is **not** a duplicate of [Go url parameters mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211241/go-url-parameters-mapping) because it is a single level (not nested levels) AND many answers in that question refer to using an external library.

Comment: But the answer you linked basically answers the question - without using external libraries you have to parse `r.URL.Path` manually and return a response based on that.

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic how ? do I have to replace pages := with getCode function as in the other reply ? I don't know it it would work in this case. Feel free to provide a full reply. That question is also 2+ years old and I am using the latest go.

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic also I tried the only valid answer and func getCode(r *http.Request, defaultCode int)  returns 2 values including an int which is irrelevant in my question.

Comment: Literally just do this `page := r.URL.Path[1:]` and then whatever logic you want to do.

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic this is working thank you! but nowhere in the previous answer I see this. There is all about looping and creating a new function. I suggest you prepare a short answer so others can benefit from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use any third-party libraries, you have to handle the parsing of the path yourself.

For start, you can do this:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    page := r.URL.Path[1:]
    // do whatever logic you want
    // mind that the page could be "multi/level/path/" as well
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http.HandleFunc.
In this function, a pattern ending in a slash defines a subtree.
You can register a handler function with the pattern "/page/" like the below example.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if is_valid_page(r.URL) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "This is a valid page")
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Error 404 - Page not found")
    }
}

func is_valid_page(page string) {
    // check here if page is valid from url 
}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/page/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

more info you can find here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am confused: as you see in my question I am already using http.HandleFunc as a routing mechanism. The issue is about dynamic creating routes based on the db entries e.g. /:page_name  as you can see on my question

Comment: the :page_name is a placeholder for any pagename
means, this handler except eg localhost:8080/page/home or localhost:8080/page/page1 etc. What you then need to do is only like your accepted answer do

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in go 1.22 without having to parse the path yourself, as suggested in the accepted answer.  As of go 1.22 go will parse placeholders in a ServeMux matched url.  From the release notes, "The new method Request.PathValue returns path wildcard values from a request and the new method Request.SetPathValue sets path wildcard values on a request."  See the Go blog article [routing-enhancements](https://go.dev/blog/routing-enhancements).  So for your case with a simple url ,

`http.Handle("GET /{page}", handlePost)`

which will handle a GET or HEAD request to paths like `/1` or `/index`. Further, the request handler can retrieve the value in the matched placeholder `{page}` using the handler's Request argument and the PathValue method; `request.PathValue("page")` would yield "1" and "index" in the examples respectively.

See the go docs for [PathValue](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@master#Request.PathValue) and [ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) for more details.

So your example could be written:

```
http.HandleFunc("GET /{page}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    page := r.PathValue("page")
    var a Page
    err := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM pages where page = ?", page).Scan(&a.Page, &a.Date, &a.Url)
    a.Year = time.Now().UTC().Year()
    if err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Page %s not found", page)
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Some error happened")
            return
        }
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, a.Url, 301)
})
```

I think the PathValue approach works better than the accepted solution using `page := r.URL.Path[1:]` because 1) it will not match urls with extra path segments, like "/page1/foo/bar" and 2) it can be target the GET method specifically without any extra code.