# Simplifying route handler to handle parameters without framework

Tags: go

In [rocket.rs](https://rocket.rs/), we've this simple route code:

```rust
#[get("/hello/<name>/<age>")]
fn hello(name: &str, age: u8) -> String {
    format!("Hello, {} year old named {}!", age, name)
}
```

where if you were to visit `http://localhost:8000/hello/John/58` in the browser, you’d see:
`Hello, 58 year old named John!`

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29211241/2441637), but the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29221954/2441637) is about a way to do `Go url parameters mapping` for single route, that could read `http://localhost:8080/blob/123/test` as `/blob/{id}/test` and display the required route.

I know there are some great routers/frameworks there, but looking to build simple code myself to understand http route handlers in a better way.

Let's say I've:

```golang
type Tender struct {
    tenderReference string
    venderCode      int
}

func (t Tender) readWrite() {
    fmt.Printf("Tender %s is ready for vendor %d to review and submit\n", t.tenderReference, t.venderCode)
}

func (t Tender) readOnly(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("Tender %s already submitted by vender %d\n", t.tenderReference, t.venderCode)
}
```

And want my routes to be something like:

1. `/api/tender/readWrite/{tenderReference}/vendor/{venderCode}` that is calling `func (t Tender) readWrite(){}`
2. `/api/tender/readOnly/{tenderReference}/vendor/{venderCode}` that is calling `func (t Tender) readOnly(){}`

How many route handler do I have to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as below, other thoughts are welcomed:

1. `404.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handle404(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "mmm, it looks you are playing around, page is not available :)\n")
}
```

2. `getField.go`

```golang
package main

import "net/http"

type ctxKey struct{}

func getField(r *http.Request, index int) string {
    fields := r.Context().Value(ctxKey{}).([]string)
    return fields[index]
}
```

3. `routes.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
)

type route struct {
    method  string
    regex   *regexp.Regexp
    handler http.HandlerFunc
}

var routes = []route{
    newRoute("GET", "/api/tender/(rw|r)/([^/]+)/vendor/([0-9]+)", apiTenders),
}

func newRoute(method, pattern string, handler http.HandlerFunc) route {
    return route{method, regexp.MustCompile("^" + pattern + "$"), handler}
}
```

4. `tendor.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

type Tender struct {
    tenderReference string
    venderCode      int
}

// Handles GET /api/tender/(rw|r)/([^/]+)/vendor/([0-9]+)
func apiTenders(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    action := getField(r, 0)
    tenderReference := getField(r, 1)
    venderCode, _ := strconv.Atoi(getField(r, 2))
    tender := Tender{tenderReference, venderCode}
    switch action {
    case "rw":
        tender.readWrite(w, r) // Display tender and allow vendor to submit feedback
    case "r":
        tender.readOnly(w, r) // Display readOnly copy of the tender
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Tendert ERROR\n")
    }
}

func (t Tender) readWrite(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Tender %s is ready for vendor %d to review and submit\n", t.tenderReference, t.venderCode)
}

func (t Tender) readOnly(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Tender %s already submitted by vender %d\n", t.tenderReference, t.venderCode)
}
```

5. `server.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type apiHandler struct{}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/api/", apiHandler{})
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // The "/" pattern matches everything, so we need to check
        // that we're at the root here.
        if req.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.NotFound(w, req)
            return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the home page!")
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func (apiHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var allow []string
    for _, route := range routes {
        matches := route.regex.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
        if len(matches) > 0 {
            if r.Method != route.method {
                allow = append(allow, route.method)
                continue
            }
            ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), ctxKey{}, matches[1:])
            route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
            return
        }
    }
    if len(allow) > 0 {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", strings.Join(allow, ", "))
        http.Error(w, "405 method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    handle404(w, r)
    //http.NotFound(w, r)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of go 1.22 go will parse placeholders in a matched url. From the release notes, "The new method Request.PathValue returns path wildcard values from a request and the new method Request.SetPathValue sets path wildcard values on a request." This is described in-depth in the Go blog article [routing-enhancements](https://go.dev/blog/routing-enhancements). Your example could be handled simply, keep much of what you had already:

```
type Tender struct {
    tenderReference string
    venderCode      int
}

func (t Tender) readWrite(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Tender %s is ready for vender %d to review and submit\n", t.tenderReference, t.venderCode)
}

func (t Tender) readOnly(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Tender %s already submitted by vender %d\n", t.tenderReference, t.venderCode)
}
```

Then a mux route with path placeholders:

```
http.HandleFunc("GET /api/tender/{action}/{tenderReference}/vender/{venderCode}", actionHandler)
```

and the RequestHandlerFunc to determine which Tender method to call.

```
func actionHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    action := r.PathValue("action")
    tenderReference := r.PathValue("tenderReference")
    venderCode := r.PathValue("venderCode")
    tender := Tender{tenderReference, venderCode}
    if action == "rw" {
        tender.readWrite(w, r)
    else if action = "r" {
        tender.readOnly(w, r)
    else
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
}
```

Note if readOnly and readWrite could fail you would want the to call w.WriteHeader(code) with the appropriate status code.

See the docs for [ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) for more details.